# Underlining in org-mode links with multiline descriptions?

Tags: org-mode, faces

**Q:** How can I stop underlining through the left "margin" in links that extend over more than one line?

The face `org-link` inherits from the face `link`, which has the underline attribute set to `t` (or at least it does by default).  Ordinarily, that's all well and good.  It gets ugly, however, if the description of the link is sufficiently long that it wraps onto more than one line, as in the following screenshot:

[image: org-mode links]

The screenshot shows the underlining extending from the left margin all the way to indentation.  That's a pretty ugly visual tick.  Is there any way to keep underlining for links, and yet *not* have the underlining extend from the margin in this way?

Comment: If you find a solution that you like, then please share it with the org maintainers because it will probably end up in the mainline: http://orgmode.org/community.html

Comment: it's also unreasonable that the underscore should stick out from the second line

Answer (score 3):

I've messed around a bit with `org-activate-bracket-links`.  I'm not
really an expert in font-locking, so I only managed to make the `"^ +"`
part of the link invisible:

```
(defun org-activate-bracket-links (limit)
  "Add text properties for bracketed links."
  (if (and (re-search-forward org-bracket-link-regexp limit t)
           (not (org-in-src-block-p)))
      (let* ((hl (org-match-string-no-properties 1))
             (help (concat "LINK: " (save-match-data (org-link-unescape hl))))
             (ip (org-maybe-intangible
                  (list 'invisible 'org-link
                        'keymap org-mouse-map 'mouse-face 'highlight
                        'font-lock-multiline t 'help-echo help
                        'htmlize-link `(:uri ,hl))))
             (vp (list 'keymap org-mouse-map 'mouse-face 'highlight
                       'font-lock-multiline t 'help-echo help
                       'htmlize-link `(:uri ,hl))))
        ;; We need to remove the invisible property here.  Table narrowing
        ;; may have made some of this invisible.
        (org-remove-flyspell-overlays-in (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
        (remove-text-properties (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)
                                '(invisible nil))
        (if (match-end 3)
            (progn
              (add-text-properties (match-beginning 0) (match-beginning 3) ip)
              (org-rear-nonsticky-at (match-beginning 3))
              (add-text-properties (match-beginning 3) (match-end 3) vp)
              (org-rear-nonsticky-at (match-end 3))
              (add-text-properties (match-end 3) (match-end 0) ip)
              (org-rear-nonsticky-at (match-end 0))
              (let ((b3 (match-beginning 3))
                    (e3 (match-end 3)))
                (save-excursion
                  (save-match-data
                    (goto-char b3)
                    (while (re-search-forward "\\(?:^ +\\| +$\\)" e3 t)
                      (org-rear-nonsticky-at (match-beginning 0))
                      (add-text-properties (match-beginning 0)
                                           (match-end 0) ip)
                      (org-rear-nonsticky-at (match-end 0)))))))
          (add-text-properties (match-beginning 0) (match-beginning 1) ip)
          (org-rear-nonsticky-at (match-beginning 1))
          (add-text-properties (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) vp)
          (org-rear-nonsticky-at (match-end 1))
          (add-text-properties (match-end 1) (match-end 0) ip)
          (org-rear-nonsticky-at (match-end 0)))
        t)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Although it does eliminate the unsightly underlining from the left margin, unfortunately, the text of the second line is now flush to the left margin instead.  I'll try to poke around a little bit more.